# задание параметров в метод

Tags: php

существует метод со своими условиями

```
public function validate_field($required=NULL,$field=NULL,$name_field=NULL, $min=NULL, $max=NULL){
       if($min=2 AND $required=='required' ){
            return '123';
        }
        if($name_field=='123' AND $min=2 AND $max=5){

            return '456';
        }
    }
```

обращаясь к нему:

```
echo    $validation->validate_field($required='required',$min=2);
 echo       $validation->validate_field($name_field='123',$min=2,$max=5);
```

return возвращает только **123** (первое условие), как задавать методу параметры, что бы условия выполнялись?

Comment: Это не питон, здесь нельзя передавать именованные аргументы.

Comment: @u_mulder, почему первое условие тогда срабатывает?

Comment: В первом вызове срабатывает, во втором __нет__.

Comment: @u_mulder, сменил их местами как внутри метода, так и очередь вызова метода, все равно срабатывает тот что 123

Comment: Я не знаю, что вы там сменили (телепатии не обучен).

Comment: @u_mulder, местами if поменял, и первую вызываю та что 456 должна возвращать, но не суть, как тогда выполнять условия если все параметры необязательны?

Comment: Передавать вместо отсутсвующих значений `null`. Или вернуться обратно на питон, например)))

Comment: передавайте один параметр - массив.

Answer (score 1):

**1** Ваш метод ожидает 5 аргументов. Если вызывать такой метод и передавать меньшее число аргуметнов, интерпретатор будет подставлять переданные данные слева-направо. При таком вызове: `$validation->validate_field($required = 'required', $min = 2);` в метод будут передоваться первые два аргумента `validate_field($required=NULL,$field=NULL` остальные передаюстя со значениями по-умолчанию.

**2** Такая форма записи `$validation->validate_field($required = 'required', $min = 2);` избыточна и беcсмыслена. Что происходит - сначала вы в переменную $required записываете строку 'required', после передаёте эту переменую в метод в качестве аргумента. Названия же переменных при вызове метода и при инициализации никак не всязаны.

**3** Ваша основная ошибка тут `if($min=2 AND $required=='required' ){`, т.к. `$min=2` это присваивание значения, то в конструкции `if` оно всегда `true`. Скорее всего вы хотели написать так:

```
 if ($min == 2 AND $required == 'required') { 
 if($name_field == '123' AND $min == 2 AND $max == 5) {
```

Comment: такая строка записи сделана по аналогии с другими языками программирования, которые позволяют передавать именованные аргументы, пропуская остальные, C# или про питон тут что-то писали, например. но очевидно, такая языковая конструкция в пхп не поддерживается.

Answer (score 1):

```
$validation->validate_field($name_field='123',$min=2,$max=5);
```

Это тоже самое, что и `$validation->validate_field('123',2,5,NULL,NULL);` Тоесть, внутри функции у вас доступны эти переменные, с данными.

```
$required='123';
$field=2;
$name_field=5;
$min=NULL;
$max=NULL;
```

Чтобы условие второе выполнилось, параметры должны передаваться последовательно, согласно порядку. То бишь так `$validation->validate_field(NULL,NULL,'123',2,5);`

Comment: сделал по другому, так для каждого поля данные могут быть разными, просто передаю их массивом, что намного проще